# Why is list iteration faster than vector iteration C++

Tags: c++, performance, stl

I have the following code:

```
main() {
  vector<int> v (1000,0);
  list<int> l (1000,0);

  clock_t begin,end;

  cout <<"Vector size: "<<v.size()<<endl;
  cout <<"List size: "<<l.size()<<endl;

  begin=clock();
  for (int i=0;i<1000000;i++)
    for (vector <int>::iterator it=v.begin();it!=v.end();it++);
  end=clock();

  cout <<v[0]<<endl;
  cout << "Vector iteration: " << (double)(end-begin)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC <<endl;


  begin=clock();
  for (int i=0;i<1000000;i++)
    for (list <int>::iterator it=l.begin();it!=l.end();it++);
  end=clock();

  list <int>::iterator it=l.begin();
  cout << *it <<endl;
  cout << "List iteration: " << (double)(end-begin)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC <<endl;
}
```

Invariably, I get the result that vector iteration is (approx) 18.3 seconds and list iteration is
(approx) 11.7 seconds. How is this possible? Is something wrong with my measurement?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I get `vector` being 0 and `list` being 1.707 on O3.

Comment: I get basically the same results as Jerry. With debug mode enabled I get that the List ist slightly slower then the vector (but I had to reduce the number of cycles to 1000 to finish it in a reasonable time.)

Comment: Here's a complimentary -1 for doing benchmarking without optimizations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the amount of time you're listing, (10-20 seconds for each) it seems nearly certain that you're compiling with optimization disabled<sup>1</sup>. This renders your results basically meaningless.

Doing a quick test on my (roughly 7 year-old) machine, with optimization enabled I get a time of 0 for vector and about 1.2-1.5 seconds for list (1.2 with VC++, 1.5 with g++).

With optimization disabled, they both slow down (a lot). With VC++ I'm seeing times of about 38 seconds for vector and 43 seconds for list. Using g++, those are more like 36 seconds for vector and 29 seconds for list. The latter (roughly) matches what you're seeing (modulo my obviously older/slower computer) so I'd guess that you were using g++ with optimization disabled.

Bottom line: what you're seeing is probably almost entirely an artifact of how the code happens to be written (e.g., possibly an extra function call in the code for vector). It's quite unrelated to the inherent efficiency of the vector or list themselves.

---

1. Just for completeness: I suppose you could get results at least somewhere close to that range simply by running the code on a really old, slow, computer. Since we're talking roughly 20 times slower than a current computer, figure something like a 150 to 233 (or so) MHz Pentium could, conceivably give results on that general order. With such an old CPU quite a few of the assumptions that go into optimizing current code probably don't really apply, so I suppose it's barely conceivable something could back-fire so badly that you'd end up with list being faster. I wouldn't really expect it even then, but with such a mismatch between the CPU the compiler expects, and the one you'd be running it on, almost anything is possible.